# Decode jQuery dataTables aoData.push parameter in controller

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTables verion 1.9.4 and spring MVC. I want to pass encoded parameters to controller using `aoData.push` method. I have used :

```js
aoData.push({"name":"message", "value":encodeURIComponent("test Message")})
```

.. But in the controller I am receiving `test%20message` instead `test message`. Is there any way to decode the dataTable parameters in controller like filters?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: can any one please help

Comment: have you searched in google? I think there is a inbuilt function to do this in java. Try this,  `System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode('test%20message', "UTF-8"));`

Comment: Or simply do find "%20" and replace " "(space).

Comment: ...Or not use `encodeURIComponent` at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
nServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "message", "value": encodeURIComponent("test 
    Message").replace(" ", "%20")});
},
```